# Enum coin toss program stuck

Tags: java

I am trying to get this coin toss program to work for Java. I'm still very new and I'm pretty sure I've messed up a bunch. Can anyone take a look? Can't figure out how to get my switch to keep looping until the user inputs 0 to stop the coin flips:

The main goal is is ask the user how many flips and out put how many heads and tail flips. Then ask if they want to keep flipping and add those flips to the one already done and I have to use ENUM to do it . . .

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CoinTossing {

    private enum Coin { HEADS, TAILS };

    private static final Random randomNumbers = new Random();

    private static final int HEADS = 1;
    private static final int TAILS = 2;




    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        int quantity = 0;
        int headSide = 0;
        int tailsSide = 0;


        System.out.println("How many times would you like to flip the coin? Enter 0 to end.");
        int flipNumber = input.nextInt();

        while (flipNumber != 0)


             quantity = quantity + flipNumber; 

            for(int x=1; x<=quantity; ++x);

                switch (Flip(null))
                {

                case HEADS:
                    headSide++;
                    break;

                case TAILS:
                    tailsSide++;
                    break;

                }   


                if (flipNumber == 0)
                    System.out.println("Your Number of flips is" + HEADS +TAILS);
    }

    private static int Flip(Random randomNumber) {
        int toss;

        toss = 1+ randomNumber.nextInt(2);
        return toss;
    }
}
```

Comment: Java is not python, indentation is used here only for readability purpose, it doesn't affect scope.

Comment: Also what is `;` doing here: `for(int x=1; x<=quantity; ++x);`?

Answer (score 3):

```
while (flipNumber != 0)



     quantity = quantity + flipNumber;
```

This loop will never break. Without braces, this is a one-line loop equivalent to

```
while (flipNumber != 0)
{
    quantity = quantity + flipNumber;
}
```

Obviously, if flipNumber is not 0, this loop will run forever.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you're not actually sending in any sort of random number generator, as the parameter you're passing in is `null`. I would recommend instantiating it, and then attempting to pass it in.

Off the top of my head, adding this line:
`Random random = new Random();`
and then changing the switch to
`switch (Flip(random))`
may fix your issue.

Comment: He is also defining both an `enum` and an `int` for `HEADS` and `TAILS`.

Comment: Actually, he has defined a static variable `randomNumbers`, and that has been instantiated...

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop has no scope outside of `quantity = quantity + flipNumber;`. If you are intending for the `while` loop to encompass the `for` loop, make sure to include braces.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CoinTossing {    
  private enum Coin { HEADS, TAILS }
  private static final Random random = new Random();

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);    
    int headSide = 0;
    int tailsSide = 0;

    System.out.println("How many times would you like to flip the coin? Enter 0 to end.");

    int flipNumber;

    while ((flipNumber = input.nextInt()) != 0) {
      for (int x = 0; x <= flipNumber; x++) {
        switch (flip()) {
          case HEADS:
            headSide++;
            break;
          case TAILS:
            tailsSide++;
            break;
        }
      }
      System.out.printf("Heads: %d Tails: %d\n", headSide, tailsSide);
    }
    System.out.println("Your number of flips is " + (headSide + tailsSide));
  }

  private static Coin flip() {
    if (random.nextBoolean()) {
      return Coin.HEADS;
    } else {
      return Coin.TAILS;
    }
  }
}
```